# How to configure Apache redirecting to another folder in OS

Tags: apache, configuration, config

Apache 2.2.29 on Windows 7.

I'm trying to achieve the following result:

- while requesting **localhost:8080/my/deep/path** (and all its subpaths) - Apache should take files from specified directory **"C:\some\path"**
- while requesting other URLs - Apache should take files from its "htdocs" directory by default

So I appended to *Apache/conf/httpd.conf* the following line
**Alias /my/deep/path "C:/some/path"**

but Apache is still not searchig for files in C:\some\path.

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong and help to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Alias /my/deep/path "C:/some/path"

<Directory "C:/some/path">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

htdocs should be configured by default in your installtion.
Check out detail info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside)

Good Luck!